# remove white space at the bottom of footer

Tags: html, css, gwtbootstrap3

I tried every thing to remove the white space after the footer , here what i wrote in Css :

```
#page-container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#content-wrap {
  padding-bottom: 100px;    /* Footer height */
}
#footer {
    background-color: #3F729B;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height:100px;
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 0 30px;
}
```

and this is in my page :

```
 <div id="page-container">
        <div id="content-wrap">
     <!-- all other page content -->

<footer id="footer" >

</footer>
    </div>
    </div>
```